# JPA persistence.xml

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, eclipselink, persistence.xml

Is there a way to make the data on the persistence.xml dynamic?
I was thinking of adding a database name property on my properties file, then the tables are created, if not existing.

Is this possible?

I'm using EclipseLink(JPA2.0) and MySQL.

Comment: @Bozho: soon I guess... I'm using JPA on my JavaSE to quicken things up...

Comment: I'll add my spring solution anyway :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use JPA in standalone environment, you can pass additional properties to `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory()`.

In application server environments you can use datasource obtained from JNDI.

Comment: Can you supply more about the Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(persitence_name, map_name)?

Comment: @Cyril: The point is that properties from the map override properties from the `persistence.xml`. So, you can pass your dynamic properties via that map.

Comment: And the map should contain the the key of the property name of the persistence.xml exactly?

Comment: @axtavt: If I won't include the classes on the map, would it affect the the classes defined on the persistence.xml?

Comment: @Cyril: That map is only for properties, it doesn't affect classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring, you can use the spring `property-placeholder-configurer` mechanism to do so. Just extend your EclipseLink vendor adapter:

```
public class ExtendedJpaVendorAdapter extends XJpaVendorAdapter {

    private Map<String, Object> vendorProperties;

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getJpaPropertyMap() {
        Map<String, Object> properties = super.getJpaPropertyMap();
        properties.putAll(vendorProperties);
        return properties;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getVendorProperties() {
        return vendorProperties;
    }

    public void setVendorProperties(Map<String, Object> vendorProperties) {
        this.vendorProperties = vendorProperties;
    }

}
```

And then you can configure these in the spring xml file.